# How to put an internal script inside a div tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a javascript inside of a div tag because i have heard its possible but for some reason the code does nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<title>XDSITE</title>
<br>
<br>

<div id=mycode style="BACKGROUND: 
url('javascript:eval(window.alert("sometext"))'"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inside `style`, it is not possible.

Comment: you are trying to execute a string of eval'd JS inside a url inside a css background property inside a style property inside a div inside your body. Why ??

Comment: Can see trying this for xss attacks but doubt it can be done without script tag. Also have quotes mismatch in html that would have to be escaped

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your HTML it is not valid, you can't run JavaScript from a style attribute.

You can run Javascript from within a `<script>` tag which really is the best way to do it.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
</script>
```

Alternatively there are some HTML elements that allow you to execute it on some events, like `onchange`, `onclick` etc.

```
<select onchange="myFunction()">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/ is a great resource for learning more about each html element, and also JavaScript as a whole.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

can you please tell here which java script framework is you are using? you can achieve this by using and template java script framework like Angular, React...
If u dont want to use any framework than you need to write pure javascript or jquery code for assigning the background css prop.

for entire body,

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')";
```

for div,

```
document.getElementById("mycode").style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- U have to give event inside expression like onclick ,mouseup Click that text -->
<div id=mycode onclick="alert('Hi ....sometext')">THARA
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <title>XDSITE</title> <br> <br> <div id=mycode style="BACKGROUND: url('javascript:eval(window.alert("sometext"))'"></div> </body> </html>
```

Answer : 
Open script in footer

```
<script>
$( "#mycode" ).click(function() {

alert( "Hai" );

});
</script>
```

I hope its working for you ...

Answer (score 0):

You can target HTML tag using `getElementById()` and then apply custom style like this 
`document.getElementById("Mydiv").style.backgroundColor="#0000"`

or apply a bunch of styles like this

```
var dev = document.getElementById("Mydiv");
dev.style.backgroundColor="#0000";
dev.style.fontSize="..";
dev.style.backgroundImage="..";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your function using "onerror" event. And also you must do some error in that case. For eg.

```
<img src="someFakeSrc" onerror='javascript:eval(window.alert("sometext"))'>
```

HTML doesn't see a src of picture then run a 'onerror' event.